# Have different color on element based on background element

Tags: javascript, css, svg

i am trying to archieve this result:
[image]

where the red background is a tilting svg based on mousemovement so the coloring has to be able to adjust and not be static.

current and obviously not satisfying result:

[image]

Do you guys know of any way on how to archive this?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: look into blend modes

Comment: As @Paulie_D said: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode

Comment: thanks. should have mentioned that i am well aware of mix-blend-mode. AFAIK there is no way to tell which specific color in which case should be applied. I might be wrong though. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: draw a red underline, draw a white underline on top and clip it to the red shape. Use crisp-edges to prevent the underlines bleeding into each other.

Answer (score 0):

So i looked deeper into mix-blend-mode and got it to work with the following code:

## html

```
<!-- absolute helper is needed as position:absolute on underline elements themselves lead to underlines not breaking correctly -->
<span class="absolute-helper">
    <!-- is used for mix-blend-mode: difference -->
    <span class="underline underline--primary">Text</span>
</span>
<!-- on top of mix-blend-mode: difference there is another layer with underlin that has mix-blend-mode: screen (opposite of multiply) -->
<span class="absolute-helper">
    <span class="underline underline--secondary">Text</span>
</span>
```

## styles

```
.absolute-helper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.underline {
  background-size: 1px 1em;
  display: inline;
  color: transparent; // hide font and just show the underlining

  &--primary {
    mix-blend-mode: difference; // shows the difference between the current and the underlying layer
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.175em $white, inset 0 -0.2em #000; // the underline, color has to be white for this to work
  }

  &--secondary {
    mix-blend-mode: screen; // opposite of multiply
    box-shadow: inset 0 -0.175em #somecolor, inset 0 -0.2em #000; // the second underline layered on top
  }
}
```

result:

[image: result]

Maybe someone will find this useful.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It seems it does not work properly with some colors so instead of using screen i used 'plus-lighter' as property which worked quite well in my case.